# setting a value based on another value in a linq query

Tags: c#

I'm changing a variable from a string a byte in my business logic but I'm not touching the database field that contains the value yet. So in the meantime, I'm looking for a c# equivalent to javascript's conditional syntax `SomeValue = (TestValue === Something) ? 1 : 2;`

Basically, the linq-to-sql query I have looks like this:

```
var TheOutput = from x in MyDC.SomeTable
                ....
                select new SomeModel()
                {
                     SomeByte = (x.SomeField === "test") ? 1 : 0
                }
```

`SomeField` is a string and if it's equal to some test string then I want the property of the output's model to be set to a byte.

Comment: Just use `==` instead of `===`

Comment: Well did you try that exact query, but using `==` instead of `===`? The conditional operator is supported in C#, but there's no `===` operator.

Comment: @JonSkeet: it's not compiling for the moment

Comment: @frenchie: Yes, but not because of a lack of conditional operator, I suspect. And next time you have a compile-time error, *please* include it in the question.

Comment: @alex: the problem is that it's saying "can't convert an int to a byte".

Comment: For conciseness, you can also remove all the parentheses in the sample code.

Comment: Cast to byte explicitly.  `SomeByte = (byte)(x.SomeField=="test"?1:0)` should work.

Comment: Ok, got it: SomeByte = (byte)(x.SomeField == "test" ? 1 : 0);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast to byte explicitly. `SomeByte = (byte)(x.SomeField=="test"?1:0)` should work.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
(x.SomeField == "test") ? 1 : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

for example

```
 select new SomeModel()
            {
                 SomeByte = (x.SomeField == "test") ? Convert.ToByte(1); : Convert.ToByte(0);
            }
```